# Ubuntu MATE 17.10 Pluma: 'Failed to load module 'pythonloader'

Tags: gedit, mate, pluma

Pluma 1.18.2 on MATE 17.10 updated Jan 13 2018

Attenpting to enable Python Console through Plugin menu.

```
(pluma:26739): libpeas-WARNING **: Failed to load module 'pythonloader': 
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpeas-1.0/loaders/libpythonloader.so: cannot 
open shared object file: No such file or directory

(pluma:26739): libpeas-WARNING **: Could not load plugin loader 'python'
```

I installed gedit (Pluma is a fork of gedit) and found that gedit does not have this issue.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit unintuitive, and you might want to report this on the [Ubuntu MATE Forums](https://ubuntu-mate.community/) as something to be fixed, but there are two packages to install to get the Python Console plugin to work (figured out with `apt search libpeas` for the first error and `apt search pluma` for the error I got after installing `libpeas-1.0-python2loader`):

```
sudo apt install libpeas-1.0-python2loader gir1.2-pluma-1.0
```

---

Now the plugin can be enabled. Click **Edit > Preferences** to bring up the dialog, go to the **plugins** tab and check the box next to Python Console

[image: preferences>plugins]

Then click **View** and toggle on **Bottom pane**. Voila.

[image: Python console]

Comment: I reported this issue to [LaunchPad as bug 1743132](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pluma/+bug/1743132). It is packaging issue, so it is more useful than contacting their community.